# how to use a variable from other class in another class in php

Tags: php

Hi there I have tried to find the answers for my problems through stackoverflow but it seems that I couldnt find anything. 
Here is my problem, I am using an MVC framework at the moment and I need to access a variable from a model at my controller. Here is my model:

```
    <?php

    use Guzzle\Http\Client;

    class Position_model extends CI_Model{

      public function get_location($location){

    // Create a client and provide a base URL
    $client = new Client('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json');

    $request = $client->get('?address=' . $location . '&sensor=false');

    // Send the request and get the response
    $response = $request->send();
    //decode json file to get the longitude and latitude

    $json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    var_dump($json);

    if($json["results"][0]["formatted_address"] AND $json["results"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]){
            $position["address"] = $json["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
            $position["latitude"] = $json["results"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lat"];
            $position["longitude"] = $json["results"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lng"];

            return $position;

            $code = 'success';
            $content = 'LOCATION FOUND ... I AM AWESOME';
            $this->output->set_status_header(201);
        }else{
            $code = 'error';
            $content = 'OOPPS LOCATION NOT FOUND';
            $this->output->set_status_header(400);

        }

    }
```

}

I need to get $position out of this class to use in a controller called schedule and append it to an other variable called $data
I have tried:

```
    $position = $this->Position_model->get_location($location)->position;
    $data += $position;
```

Please help me !!!!
However apparently, this doesnt work and give me error like: undefined position or calling non-object property

Comment: for a function called "get_location" there are a little too many side-effects for my taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `get_location` is the position.  You do not need the extra `->position`

Your code should be

```
$position = $this->Position_model->get_location($location);
$data += $position;
```

The error is telling you that you are attempting the treat something that isn't an object like one.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer to fix your problem:

```
$position = $this->Position_model->get_location($location);
$data += $position;
```

But you have other problems in your code. You have code like

```
$code = 'success';
$content = 'LOCATION FOUND ... I AM AWESOME';
$this->output->set_status_header(201);
```

that will never be executed, because it's after a return statement. So the execution of the program will never reach it. You'll have to put those BEFORE the return statement.

Also, I would recommend against updating the property $this->output in the model. I'd return something to the controller, and make this set the right HTTP headers based on the returned value. Returning things and changing object state at the same time can lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's actually one of my probs :D